# Is multi threaded delete from mongodb blocking?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-mongodb

I am working on a task where I would need to delete some very large records from mongodb. sometimes records are between 2M and 3M. I am trying to make that as fast as it could be.

My idea was to use some kind of thread pool and divide this number into some like 20 threads that each delete a part of the collection. Before I go further in this approach I would like to know if that is a good(promising) approach or not. My main concern is that if maybe this is not possible in mongo and I will have a blocking behaviour in the db and basically the threads will wait for each other to finish deleting.

also I would be happy if any other approaches/solutions are suggested.

the project language is Java/Spring.

Answer (score 0):

Before making anything "as fast as it could be" you need to understand where the bottleneck is (typically CPU, memory or disk) so that your changes actually make a difference.

When it comes to deletes, there is some overhead in the delete operation (client has to send the command to the server, server has to parse it, etc.).

Assuming you have *a large number of deletes*, using 2 application threads for deleting may be a good idea to reduce this overhead when measuring wallclock time.

The *size of documents* being deleted doesn't matter.

If you are *assuming* that the server will be I/O bound due to document size, then sending more requests to it concurrently wouldn't help at all (in fact that would be counterproductive).